# Is there a way to directly style text content generated in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a tic-tac-toe game, and built the squares of the gameboard with p HTML elements. Whenever a square is clicked on, I'm running a function that takes a variable of turn, which is equal to 'X', and inserts it into the square when the square is clicked on. The function also toggles the variable's text, so 'O' is next.

Is there a way to directly style these 'X's and 'O's? I've tried to style the p elements color and font-size, and this worked, but now I'm trying to style the position of the 'X's and 'O's within the square.

Comment: use padding/margin/text-align/vetical-align etc etc to position text within an element

Comment: @Bravo I'm able to use text-align but vertical-align isn't doing anything for me, and I'm not able to use the position property in the way that I want

Comment: `vertical-align` depends on `display` ... as for *not able to use the position property in the way that I want* - how do you want to use it?

Comment: @Bravo I want to be able to center the 'X's and 'O's in each individual square that gets clicked on

Comment: yes, so ... what have you done about it?

Comment: @Bravo I set position to relative but it won't target the text content within the p element.

Comment: yeah, at a guess you're not doing it right - it's a guess, because you're not showing how you're doingit

Answer (score 1):

You can add the classes to your CSS file and then add them to the corresponding elements.

An example:

```
let elementX = document.getElementById("element_x");

elementX.classList.add("element_x_class");
```